# Every even number can be expressed as either $4q$ or $4q+2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that every positive even integer $n$ can be expressed as $n=4q$ or $n=4q+2$, $\forall q\in Z$.

I  expressed $n$ as $n=4q+r$ using Euclid's lemma and I have been able to prove that $n=4q+0, n=4q+1, n=4q+2, n=4q+3$. Among these $n=4q, n=4q+2$ are even. conversely it is proved. But my basic question is why should I begin by writing $n=4q+r$ and not $n=5q+r$

Comment: Is $5$ even number?

Comment: Of course it is odd. But why should not I start my proof from numbers other than 4.

Comment: You can as $$n\equiv0,2,\cdots,2m-4,2m-2\pmod{2m}$$

Comment: Of course. We can take any even number and the reason is as simple as it's answer (which says that any integer multiplied only with even number will result in even number).

Comment: The question is asking about writing $n$ as $4q$ or $4q+2$, so why would you start by using $5q$?

Answer (score 2):

Every even integer $n$ can be written as $n=2m,$ for some integer $m.$ Now, there are two possibilities: $m$ is even ($m=2q$) or $m$ is odd ($m=2q+1$) for some integer $q.$ In the first case we have

$$n=2m=4q$$

and in the second case

$$n=2m=2(2q+1)=4q+2.$$

Another way to see why we can express any even number as before is consider the remainder when we divide by $4.$ There are only two possibilities: remainder zero ($n=4q$) and remainder two ($n=4q+2.$)

If you try to do the same with a expression of the form $n=5q+r$ then you don't get any advantage, in general, since the remainder of the division by $5$ can take any value from $0$ to $4=5-1.$ Note that
$$1=5\cdot 0 +\color{blue}{1},2=5\cdot 0 +\color{blue}{2},3=5\cdot 0 +\color{blue}{3},4=5\cdot 0 +\color{blue}{4},5=5\cdot 1 +\color{blue}{0}.$$

Comment: That answers the title, not the actual question posted.

Answer (score 1):

Because $n = 5q + r$ is actually a digression from what you're trying to prove.

The thing is, with $n = 4q + r$, you can theoretically set $q$ and $r$ to any integer values you want. But, if $|r| \geq 4$, you can choose a different value of $q$ so that then $0 \leq r < 4$ and then that way you reduce the infinity of $\mathbb{Z}$ to just four cases: $r = 0$, $r = 1$, $r = 2$, $r = 3$. If $r = 0$, then $n = 4q$ and it's an even number. If $r = 1$, then $n$ is odd. If $r = 2$, then $n = 4q + 2$ and it's even. And if $r = 3$, then $n$ is odd. You don't have to worry about $r = 4$ because then you can increment $q$ to $q + 1$, reset $r$ to $0$ and then you're back to $n = 4q + 0$. If $r = 5$, you can likewise change things so your dealing with $r = 1$ instead, etc., etc.

But with $n = 5q + r$, you'd have way more than just four cases to worry about. I think you'd have like twenty cases to worry about, which you'd wind up converting to $n = 4q + r$, e.g., if $n = 5q + r$ and $q$ is a multiple of $4$ and $r$ is even, this can be rewritten as $n = 20k + r$ where $k = \frac{q}{4}$. So why not start with $n = 4q + r$ right from the start?

By the way, you could also do $n = 8q + r$. You'd have just eight cases to consider, but still, you'd be making things more complicated than they need to be. You're first instinct to use $n = 4q + r$ was correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ By the Division with Remainder Algorithm

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad n\, =\, 4q + r,\ \ \ 0 \le r < 4$

Now notice that $\ 2\mid n\iff 2\mid 4q+r\iff 2\mid r$

That is: $\,n\,$ is even iff its remainder mod $4$ is even iff $\,r \in \{0,2\}$

**Remark** $ $ We began by writing $\,n\,$ in the form $\, 4q+r\,$ (vs. $\,5q+r),\,$ because that form is a *slight* *generalization* of the form that we seek, viz.  $\,4q+r,\ r\in \{0,2\},\,$ already having the same modulus/quotient $(= 4)$ as the sought form, so leaving only further analysis of the remainder $\,r,\,$ which succumbs to a simple *parity* argument.